# How to store a string in an object and retrieve it safely later?

Tags: programming, c++, string, memory

I'm writing a program where I will be able to toggle between multiple banks, and each bank has 4 presets on it. Right now, I'm trying to give each preset a name that is assigned on creation.

I have an object I called `StoredDataManager`, which will handle all the banks. In its constructor, I do this:

```
for (byte i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_BANKS; i++) {
  Bank bank;
  _banks[i] = &bank;
}
```

`_banks` is declared like this: `Bank* _banks[NUMBER_OF_BANKS];` in the `.h`file of `StoredDataManager`.

A bank has 4 presets, like this:

```
Preset* _A;
Preset* _B;
Preset* _C;
Preset* _D;
```

Which I initialize as this:

```
Preset preset(presetName, presetData);
...
_A = &preset; ...
```

Where `presetName` is `"CHR"`, and `presetData` doesn't matter, because I'm just trying to get the name to work.

In the preset, the name is saved like this: `char _presetName[4];`.
It is returned like this:

```
char* Preset::getPresetName() {
  return _presetName;
}
```

I try to print a preset's name like this:

```
Serial.println(_banks[0]->getPreset('A')->getPresetName());
```

But, right now it simply returns `C§`.

Why is that? I suspect it has to do with the memory being erased or overwritten.

EDIT:
Here is the code of `getPreset`:

```
Preset* Bank::getPreset(char presetLocation) {
  switch (presetLocation) {
    case PRESET_LOCATION_1:
      return _A;
    case PRESET_LOCATION_2:
      return _B;
    case PRESET_LOCATION_3:
      return _C;
    case PRESET_LOCATION_4:
      return _D;
    default:
      return NULL;
  }
}
```

I think now that I'll turn this into 4 separate functions, like `getA`, `getB` and so on, but this what it is the moment. `PRESET_LOCATION_1` is just a `#define PRESET_LOCATION_1 'A'`.

EDIT 2:
I start in the main arduino `.ino` file with this:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  StoredDataManager storedDataManager;
}
```

This triggers this constructor:

```
StoredDataManager::StoredDataManager() {
  for (byte i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_BANKS; i++) {
    Bank bank;
    _banks[i] = &bank;
  }
  _currentBankIndex = 0;
  Serial.println(_banks[0]->getPreset('A')->getPresetName());
}
```

This is `_banks`: `Bank* _banks[NUMBER_OF_BANKS];`.
The initializing of the `bank` object runs this constructor: (PRESET_LOCATION_1, 2, 3, and 4 just being `'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'`)

```
Bank::Bank() {
  addPreset("CHR", "Some data", PRESET_LOCATION_1);
  addPreset("CHR", "Some data", PRESET_LOCATION_2);
  addPreset("CHR", "Some data", PRESET_LOCATION_3);
  addPreset("CHR", "Some data", PRESET_LOCATION_4);
}
```

Which calls this function:

```
void Bank::addPreset(const char* presetName, String presetData, char presetLocaton) {
  Preset preset(presetName, presetData);
  switch (presetLocaton) {
    case PRESET_LOCATION_1:
      _A = &preset; break;
    case PRESET_LOCATION_2:
      _B = &preset; break;
    case PRESET_LOCATION_3:
      _C = &preset; break;
    case PRESET_LOCATION_4:
      _D = &preset; break;
  }
}
```

Then, above in the `StoredDataManage`s constructor, this line is hit:

```
Serial.println(_banks[0]->getPreset('A')->getPresetName());
```

And that's where I try to log out the preset name.

Comment: The use of dynamic memory on a constrained system like avr and the word "safely" as a goal probably do not belong in the same posting.  That said, an immediate problem is that `'A'` does not mean what you think it does - specifically it is an integer constant of value 65, ie, the ascii code of a capital `A`  You should probably show the code of `getPreset()`

Comment: @ChrisStratton I posted the code for `getPreset()`. I do know that it is the character `'A'`, though. As I mention at the end there, I'm probably going to change how I get the presets.

Comment: Where do you call preset()?  With a pointer to what?  That was initialized how?  Without including your code, this is unanswerable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Tried to explain the flow together with the code now.

Comment: Just as a style thing, identifiers starting with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter are reserved by the C++ standard. You should get out of the habit of using them for your own variables.

Comment: @Nick Gammon Thanks, didn't know that. Just seemed like the natural name when the preset location name was A :) Ill change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Bank::addPreset(const char* presetName, String presetData, char presetLocaton)
{
  Preset preset(presetName, presetData);

  switch (presetLocaton)
  {
    case PRESET_LOCATION_1:
      _A = &preset; break;
    case PRESET_LOCATION_2:
      _B = &preset; break;
    case PRESET_LOCATION_3:
      _C = &preset; break;
    case PRESET_LOCATION_4:
      _D = &preset; break;
  }
}
```

I can't see how this is going to work because you are storing somewhere outside a function a pointer to a local variable *inside* the function. As soon as `addPreset` exits the variable `preset` will go out of scope, and a pointer to it will be undefined.

---

You should probably do a `new` to make a new instance of `Preset` which it is then valid to store outside the scope of the function.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was thinking as long as I stored a reference to it, the data at that memory location wouldn't be removed. I'll work on changing that tomorrow. Thanks! Any idea as to how I could create an object that would not be garbage collected that would work in this situation?

Comment: I'll try newing the objects tomorrow. I guess I have the same problem with the banks, then.

Comment: Yes, very much so. Don't assign to some variable a thing that will go out of scope, as you did there. As for garbage collection, there is no default garbage collection in C++.

Comment: Ah, right. It has been some time since I coded C++ :) Thanks!